# How to create a floating layout for mobile with two+ elements?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a layout for mobile devices which will list containers of elements. Depending on device screen width I want to show more or less elements in one row.

There are some criterias I need to match:

1. Maxwidth of 180px per element
2. Fixed margin of 5px between elements, but not on right, left of container
3. Element will grow, shrink in width depending on device width
4. If there is enough space for a 3rd, 4th element it should be in the same row
5. Elements that do not fit into one row will snap to the next row with a margin-top 5px
6. The boxes in one row should have the same hight

My try looks like this so far:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NJZyeZ

CSS:

```css
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.column {
  float: left;
  margin-right:5px; 
  max-width: 170px;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the end I want to loop through my array of elements and build the page. So with that approach in my code I have rows and columns, which would require to know the width of the device in order to know how many elements are in one row.

What would be a better approach to achieve what I want?

Comment: Frameworks such as Bootstrap do indeed have multiple media queries set to certain breakpoints which essentially do `width: calc(100% / columnCount)`. You could always use something like flexbox or CSS Grid though.

Comment: I am using jQuery mobile and would rather not like to add more frameworks. Could you explain what you mean with flesbox or CSS Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS Grid**:

You just have to define the properties of your grid; including the behavior of filling the row; min or max size of columns and rows, gap between items, etc.

In your case you know that the max amount of columns you can have in a single row is 4 so you can set `grid-template-columns` to:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(100px, 180px));`

So you always get at most 4 columns with each item having a minimum width of 100px and a max width of 180px;

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(80px, 180px));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

**Flexbox**

This would require a bit more tweaking to fully behave like you need to, but it is possible as well.

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0 -2.5px;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 180px;
  margin: 0 2.5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Would that work on all modern mobile devices? I got one major issue that I could not resolve using your code. Depending on size, the last element in the row is not entirely visible. If there is not enough space in the row for the entire element, the element should move to the next row. Is there something missing, or did I not implement correctly?

Comment: Support is really good for both approaches, so not much of a problem there: [CSS Grid](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid) ,  [Flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) ... I'm not sure what you mean; keep in mind I tried to set a minimum with so the boxes were displayed; maybe something to do with that? Try playing around with the properties defined to see where the issue is :)

Comment: Got it! repeat(auto-fit, minmax(145px, auto) That seems to have solve the issue magically :-). Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you for your help with grid layout. I implemented it and it looks like it is not supported by Safari 10, Edge 15 and some older versions. It looks quite bad on those browsers: https://watchgurus.de/omega/ Do you have a suggestion on how to fix this with a fallback in a way that it looks at least OK?

Comment: Being quite honest I don't know of something like a *fallback* for CSS Grid /: I think the "solution" would be to build a different structure with something more compatible (like Flexbox) but of course that would be more work

Comment: Never mind, I switched to flex layout for desktop view and kept grid for mobile devices. The problem with grid layout is that edge 15 is not supporting it (2years old) and safari 10. The first person I showed the page in real live had this old safari browser which was kind of embarasing. So at this point in time I can not recommend grid for production use if you target a larger audience. Flex looks great even on IE 11. PS: I am wondering who downvotes such a question?!

Comment: Good, however now that Edge will be switching to Chromium maybe it'll have better compatibility; but who knows, CSS Grid is still developing and modern versions of browsers have good support, so all that remains is to wait for people relying on older browsers to catch up

Answer (score 0):

This hits most of the notes, best of which is the flexibility and justification to the edges:

```css
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 -5px -5px 0;
}
.column {
  flex: 1 0 180px;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:#aaa;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
     <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
     <h2>Column 4</h2>
     <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <h2>Column 5</h2>
     <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column 6</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column 7</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Simran, I tried your approach but got stuck due to the growing center space.